# Motor controller oscilations with flyback diodes

Tags: motor, driver

Have some motor controller oscillations with flyback diodes when they were added to the build. They emerge with higher rates of signal amount making by controller. So there is a need to reduce the maximum force applied a bit.

The application it DIY FFB wheel driver. They were there and emerges also with the shortest wires and with ordinary 1n4007 diodes while testing there connection plan to the build.

Shall it be overviewed or left as is? Not a big deal, but decided to ask) 
May be a distance to the mosfets from flybacks, are a bit higher for it?

https://youtu.be/UwYMtKqMirE
https://youtu.be/moSy942r6xg

Comment: Why do you perceive it as a problem?

Comment: I just wondering. It requires some max power reduction due to it.

Comment: Any thoughts some more, on the topic please?)

Answer (score 0):

I guess Solved. The GND side of the flyback diodes should be connected directly to power supply GND, not through the pwm side of the board. Was tested and showed much better results. 
[image]